# Could not find plugin "proposal-numeric-separator"

Tags: reactjs, build, yarnpkg

How to fix `Could not find plugin "proposal-numeric-separator"`, I get this error when I try to build my React application, I have not ejected the application yet:

```
./src/index.js
Error: [BABEL] /home/pc/Downloads/project/src/index.js: Could not find plugin "proposal-numeric-separator". Ensure there is an entry in ./available-plugins.js for it. (While processing: "/home/pc/Downloads/project/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/index.js$0")
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I have tried to download Babel and the dependency Proposal Numeric Separator, remove the Node Modules, clean the Yarn cache; but nothing worked.

I'm using Yarn 1.22.4 and Node 13.11.0, but I have also tried with NPM 6.13.7.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. +1

Comment: Other people are having the same issue: https://www.reddit.com/r/angular/comments/flymj5/build_failing_please_help/ The suggested solution did not work for me.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The following steps work:

1. Add the following line to `package.json`:

```js
"resolutions": { 
  "@babel/preset-env": "7.5.5" 
},
```

2. Run the following command:

```
$ npx npm-force-resolutions
```

3. Install dependencies:

```
$ npm install
# or 
$ yarn
```

4. Build your project:

```
$ yarn build
```

Take a look at this  [Github Issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8680)

Comment: Just added `resolutions`, removed *node_modules* and installed the dependencies. It worked, thanks. **Observation**: I have tested the build and everything is ok.

Comment: man, you save my life. How do you know about this answer? You have got my awesome like, buddy. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CarlosQuerioz I think that the reason is the last topic from [this](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/#toc-why-would-you-want-to-do-this) documentation: "Your dependency defines a broad version range and your sub-dependency just got a problematic update so you want to pin it to an earlier version"

Comment: Thank you man. I don't know what happened. How does it happen suddenly. I coul build it normally until yesterday and today I had to do this to fix it?

Comment: @user3746480 It is a problem with the babel dependencies. The most probable  cause might be removing or updating node modules. Thats why enforcing a given working version fixes it

Comment: awsome, in my case, after running  audit fix command ran into this issue thanks for a day, be careful guys while running such command while it may be essential but at the cost of a day

Answer (score 62):

Try this, it works: `npm i @babel/compat-data@7.8.0`

I have just used it like 10 minutes ago, and it's working fine.

[Related issue going on github about this. Click Here!](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17262)

Comment: Works for me. Most straight-on answer IMHO.

Comment: Happy to hear that, Thanks Andy B-)

Comment: Thanks, I tired the other methods described here but this worked on the first try

Comment: My installed @babel/preset-env version is 7.8.6 and installing the exact same version of @babel/compat-data worked for me!

Comment: Update: this is still working. Thanks!

Comment: @Kobi I am glad it is. Have a great weekend :)

Answer (score 16):

From the corresponding [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8680#issuecomment-601961405) in create-react-app,

> Update react-scripts to 3.4.1 in your package.json file and remove
>   node_modules as well as package-lock.json/yarn.lock and re-install.

Answer (score 15):

**Why this problem happened**?:

It's an issue of conflicts between internal packages used by `babel`.

Adding a new plugin to `@babel/compat-data` breaks old `@babel/preset-env` versions. This is because `preset-env` iterates over `compat-data`'s plugins, and throws if the plugin isn't defined in preset-env's `available-plugins.js` file.

This is the merge that fixed the issue: https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/11201/files/a88a00750c61ff89f1622d408d67108719f21ecd

**Solution**:

- Delete `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`
- Delete `node_modules` folder
- In `package.jon` I have adjusted the version numbers of these packages to:

```
    ...
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/compat-data": "^7.8.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
        ...
    },
    ...
    "resolutions": {
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.0"
    }
```

- Run `npm install`
- Run `npm run build`

Answer (score 9):

Reference: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17262

I found two solution

a ) Install babel compat

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/compat-data": "7.8.0",
}
```

b) Install plugin-proposal-numeric-separator

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator
```

install this version only 7.8.0

2. Angular CLI can create this kind of issue. Go to package json and change it to

   build-angular": "0.803.17"

*please don't add ^ or ~* .

Answer (score 7):

I faced similar issue and i was able to fix it by updating all babel dependencies to latest version. I'm not aware of the exact issue with babel. However, the below mentioned step worked for me.

Step 1: identify and remove all babel related dependencies from package.json

```
npm remove @babel/runtime @babel/core @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs @babel/plugin-transform-runtime @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react babel-eslint babel-jest babel-loader
```

Step 2: re-install babel dependencies

```
npm install --save @babel/runtime

npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs @babel/plugin-transform-runtime @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react babel-eslint babel-jest babel-loader
```

PS: The above list of babel dependencies will differ for your project.

Answer (score 7):

I just changed react-script version from 3.0.1 to 3.4.1

Answer (score 7):

You can use this command, which has worked for me.

```
npm i @babel/compat-data@7.8.0
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm using angular & this worked for me, simply changed the version of @babel/compat-data from `^7.8.0` to just `7.8.0`, the package-lock.json is having newer version which has bugs.

Inside package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/compat-data": "7.8.0",
}
```

Comment: yes  "@babel/compat-data": "7.9.0", doesn't work https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17262#issuecomment-603396857

Answer (score 5):

In package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/compat-data": "7.8.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
  ....
  "resolutions": {
     "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7"
  }
```

it is working for me. You can read more

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17262#issuecomment-603396857

Answer (score 4):

Its just a 4 step process.

**Reason:**
This happens because of a package missing in babel. This will happen even if you create angular app using `ng new` command.

**Solution**

1. Install `plugin-proposal-numeric-separator` using the following code in terminal.

   ```
   npm install --save @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator
   ```
2. Once it is done navigate to the file as shown below.

   **node_modules > @babel > preset-env > available-plugins.js**
3. In available-plugins.js below `exports.default = void 0;` copy and paste the following code.

   ```
   var _pluginProposalNumericSeparator = _interopRequireDefault(require("@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator"));
   ```
4. In available-plugins.js within `var _default` object declaration copy and paste the following code.

   ```
   "proposal-numeric-separator": _pluginProposalNumericSeparator.default,
   ```

And it is done.

Comment: I think that is not a valid solution, please follow this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60780664/could-not-find-plugin-proposal-numeric-separator/60892324#60892324

Answer (score 4):

In my angular 8 application, although I did not have any direct dependancy of react-scripts package and did not have it in `package.json` either but started getting this error on build. It was likely used as a depedancy by other packges.

By reading this post on [github](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8680), I added it as dependancy in package.json `"react-scripts": "3.4.1"` and run npm install the build started working just fine.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

- Delete `package-lock.json`
- Delete `node_modules`
- Run `npm i`

Answer (score 1):

try this , this working with me .

```
npm i @babel/compat-data@7.8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

[Add `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` to `.env` file](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8680#issuecomment-601906432) to make the build work without ejecting and follow the below steps:

- Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
- Add `"resolutions": { "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7" }` to `package.json`
- Run `npm install npm-force-resolutions --save-dev`
- Run `npm install`
- Run `npx npm-force-resolutions`
- Run `npm install` again
- Run `npm run build`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've got a corrupted `node_modules` folder.
My yarn install simply stopped in the middle by a power surge.

By running:

```
rm -rf node_modules
yarn
```

My problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

worked for me.
npm install @babel/compat-data@~7.8.0

Answer (score -2):

I just had this happen to me. The To fix it I ran `yarn build` with sudo privileges.