# Could not find plugin "proposal-numeric-separator" in angular app

Tags: angular, npm

I am getting below error on running `ng build --prod`.

```
An unhandled exception occurred: [BABEL] /root/catch-up-enterprise/dist/polyfills-es5.8e4ba13e1c10f0a37bb4.js: Could not find plugin "proposal-numeric-separator". Ensure there is an entry in ./available-plugins.js for it. (While processing: "/root/catch-up-enterprise/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js") See "/tmp/ng-sg4wHH/angular-errors.log" for further details
```

**Error log:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# more /tmp/ng-sg4wHH/angular-errors.log
[error] Error: [BABEL] /root/catch-up-enterprise/dist/polyfills-es5.8e4ba13e1c10f0a37bb4.js: Could not find plugin "proposal-numeric-separator". Ensure there is an entry 
in ./available-plugins.js for it. (While processing: "/root/catch-up-enterprise/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")
    at getPlugin (/root/catch-up-enterprise/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js:67:11)
    at Array.from.map.pluginName (/root/catch-up-enterprise/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js:258:62)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at _default (/root/catch-up-enterprise/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js:258:43)
    at /root/catch-up-enterprise/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:19:12
    at /root/catch-up-enterprise/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:179:14
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/root/catch-up-enterprise/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js:26:3)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/root/catch-up-enterprise/node_modules/gensync/index.js:254:32)
    at evaluateAsync (/root/catch-up-enterprise/node_modules/gensync/index.js:284:5)
    at Function.errback (/root/catch-up-enterprise/node_modules/gensync/index.js:108:7)
    at errback (/root/catch-up-enterprise/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js:70:18)
    at async (/root/catch-up-enterprise/node_modules/gensync/index.js:183:31)
    at onFirstPause (/root/catch-up-enterprise/node_modules/gensync/index.js:209:13)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

**Steps tried:**
    I thought the issue is missing  proposal-numeric-separator module, so installed the module via below command

```
    npm i @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator
```

Still the issue did not resolved, so tried the answer given in the [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60780664/could-not-find-plugin-proposal-numeric-separator), still same error occurred.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Thanks to nicolo-ribaudo from [issue8680](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8680)

Adding the dependency @babel/compat-data": "7.8.0" fixed the issue for me.

```
vi package.json

    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/compat-data": "7.8.0",
        ...
    }

npm install

ng build --prod
```

Comment: Don't forget to run `npm i` after adding the dependency.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

> It work's for me

Step 1: add in in your devDependencies:  "**@babel/compat-data": "7.8.0**"

Step 2: run - **npm install**