# Npm run build failing when running docker build

Tags: angular, docker, npm, npm-install

I'm getting an error when I run docker build . The problem is when docker runs `npm install -f`, initially I changed the command to `npm install` but the problem still persists. The logs are too long I can't post them here for more detail [here](https://gist.github.com/pmutua/a11a2ea5eaa69c1647f229dd0b6870a2). Below is a snippet of the logs, the last part of the logs which is failing to complete the build. I have also included the `Dockerfile`.

**Note:**
When I run `npm run build` locally on my machine it works perfectly tried to change `npm run build --aot` to `npm run build` in the `Dockerfile` but the problem still persists.

## Logs

```
Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
An unhandled exception occurred: [BABEL] /app/dist/e-county/src-app-receipting-receipting-module-es2015.js: Could not find plugin "proposal-numeric-separator". Ensure there is an entry in ./available-plugins.js for it. (While processing: "/app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")
See "/tmp/ng-j8ToFT/angular-errors.log" for further details.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! e-county@0.0.0 build: `node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the e-county@0.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-27T17_41_05_761Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build --aot' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

## Dockerfile

```
# stage 1
FROM node:latest as node

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .


RUN npm i -f && npm audit fix

RUN npm run build --aot

# stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine


RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY  --from=node /app/nginx/*  /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=node /app/dist/e-county /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: Might be a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60780664/could-not-find-plugin-proposal-numeric-separator

Answer (score 6):

After inspecting the logs below, I noticed that issue was the node version I was using which was `v10.15.1` and also had a deprecated package [fsevents@1.2.13](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents/v/1.2.13). From the `Dockerfile` I was trying to install the latest node version which is incompatible with the deprecated package version. I later upgraded the application to **Angular 9**. There are a couple of new breaking changes in this [version](https://angular.io/guide/updating-to-version-9). Changed also the `Dockerfile` I didn't need to force install with `npm i -f` or run `npm audit fix` had all the dependencies and were up to date. It's important to worth mention, always check your dependencies in your app if there are up to date and find out if there are any breaking changes involved from the package documentation this would save you a lot of time from fixing dependency issues.

```
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":"<8.10.0"} (current: {"node":"10.15.1","npm":"6.12.0"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":"<8.10.0"} (current: {"node":"10.15.1","npm":"6.12.0"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular/animations@8.2.14 requires a peer of @angular/core@8.2.14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.901.7 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@>=9.0.0 < 10 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.901.7 requires a peer of typescript@>=3.6 < 3.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@9.1.7 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@>=9.0.0 < 10 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@9.1.7 requires a peer of typescript@>=3.6 < 3.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@8.0.2 requires a peer of node-sass@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@8.0.2 requires a peer of fibers@>= 3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-subresource-integrity@1.4.0 requires a peer of html-webpack-plugin@^2.21.0 || ~3 || >=4.0.0-alpha.2 <5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.901.7
added 254 packages from 127 contributors, removed 28 packages, updated 169 packages and moved 25 packages in 132.099s
fixed 4 of 9 vulnerabilities in 2093 scanned packages
  3 package updates for 5 vulnerabilities involved breaking changes
  (use `npm audit fix --force` to install breaking changes; or refer to `npm audit` for steps to fix these manually)
```

**Updated Dockerfile**

```
# stage 1
FROM node:latest as node

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm i 

RUN npm run build --prod

# stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine

RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY  --from=node /app/nginx/*  /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=node /app/dist/e-county /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Answer (score 0):

Check "outputPath" in angular.json. The path passed in COPY --from=node its needed to be the same